# Can not render image in flutter Splash screen/First Screen(iOS only)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am adding an background image to the Splash screen, but is not rendering the image. Sometime it load sometime not.If I load in the Second screen it loads properly. The issue is in iOS not in Android.
Here is a sample code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  //runApp()
  // SplashWidget
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: UIData.buildTheme(),
    home: SplashS(),
  ));
}
class SplashS extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(body:Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 
            child:Image.asset(
          "images/image_name.png",
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        )),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the image path in your `pubspec.yaml`?

```
assets:
  - images/image_name.png
```

Comment: yes... Its working properly in android  but not in iOS.

Comment: Check the build phases on iOS Runner project and make sure it is copying the assets folder